# Getting SAXParseException when using task:annotation-driven tag in Spring MVC

Tags: java, xml, spring-mvc, web, saxparseexception

I am writing  a web application with Spring Framework 4.0.6 and I have to schedule a small routine to run everyday at the same time.
I am trying it by using the `@Scheduled` annotation and adding the `<task:annotation-driven />` tag in my dispatcher-servlet.xml , but I get a `SAXParseException` when the application starts.
My xml file is this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!-- was: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/     http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/     http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd ">
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>
    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="my.package.name.controllers" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <task:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

The full error I get is this:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 30 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 30; columnNumber: 30; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'task:annotation-driven'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it!
The problem was in the `/` characters, at the end of `http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/` and `http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/`. Just removed them, like in `http://www.springframework.org/schema/task` and now it works just fine.